# Reverse calculation of matrix in Python

Tags: python, matrix

I need to do the reverse calculation of matrix, given by:

```
rotation=np.matrix([[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, math.cos(4*math.radians(a)), math.sin(4*math.radians(a)), 0], [0, math.sin(4 * math.radians(a)), -math.cos(4 * math.radians(a)), 0], [0, 0, 0, -1]])
a=60

X=np.matrix('1 ;-1 ;0 ;0')

a1=rotation*X

a1=[[ 1.       ]
 [ 0.5      ]
 [ 0.8660254]
 [ 0.       ]]
```

Is it possible to do the reverse calculation to find the value of `a`, given `rotation` and `x`?

Thank you.

Comment: do you mean the inverse? in numpy this would be [`inv`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.inv.html). and shouldn't you use the [`dot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html?highlight=dot#numpy.dot) product?

Comment: Are you looking for np.inv? Or np.linalg.solve?

Comment: Also, matrix is deprecated.

Comment: Whatt is   `IV` ?

Comment: @Mad Physicist. IV is X. I am sorry for the type..I have changed it in the question.

Comment: @hiro protagonist. dot product is same with multiplication of matrix,right?

Comment: If that's your equation, what's the actual question ?

Comment: I need an equation to find `a` for the given `rotation` and `x`.

Comment: Is it a math problem or a programming problem?
math.acos() or math.asin() may help

Comment: you have a vector `x` and a vector `y` that is just `x` rotated around one axis by an angle `a`? and you want to find `a`? in that case (this is just symbolical): `dot(x, y) = norm(x) * norm(y) * cos(a)`. the rest should follow from there.

Comment: @hiro protagonist. How to dot(a1,X) since the shape of matrices is 4x1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i am guessing right, you mean this:

first, your matrix is not a [rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix); the sign is in the wrong place...

then i will ignore the factor of `4`; you may reinsert that yourself.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import norm
from numpy import dot, cos, sin, arccos

x = np.array((1, -1, 0, 0))
y = np.array((1, 0.5, 0.8660254, 0))

# just considering indices 1 and 2
cos_a = dot(x[1:3], y[1:3])/(norm(x[1:3]) * norm(y[1:3]))

a_rad = arccos(cos_a)
a_deg = np.rad2deg(a_rad)

print(a_deg)  # 120
```

and to check that the (correct) brotation indeed reproduces `y`:

```
rot = np.array((
    (1, 0, 0 , 0),
    (0, cos(a_rad), -sin(a_rad), 0),
    (0, sin(a_rad), cos(a_rad), 0),
    (0, 0, 0, 1))
)

print(dot(rot, x))  # [ 1.         0.5       -0.8660254  0.       ]
```

Comment: The value of `a_deg` should be 60 isn't it?

Comment: why *should* it be like this? with a rotation matrix as in my example the angle **is** 120 (as shown by my code). and as i said: ignored a factor of 4; changed your matrix.